# How to use Constructor for JsonObject Load method

Tags: c#, json

I am using the code from MSDN documentation, to load the JSON file inside my Application Project. I wanted to use JsonObject to get the contents from the .json file.

Here is the code I am using,

```
Stream fs = File.Open(
@"C:\Users\AfzaalAhmad\Documents\The VS Org\Personal Diary\events.json",
FileMode.Open);
JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject)JsonObject.Load(fs);
```

But when it is executed it gives me the following error. Please note that the file is **Empty**.

> System.FormatException

The snapshot for the error is as

[image]

In the documents I read that the `.Load()` method takes a Parameter of System.IO.Stream type, the code shows same return type for the `fs`. But when it is executed it gives me the error. What should I be doing, in order to correct this error?

Comment: `FormatException` is thrown when it can't automatically convert your file into a JSON object, you could have something wrong in the file... try to copy paste that file contents and use a JSON validator, like http://jsonlint.com/ to test if you have a valid JSON input...

Comment: Oh, maybe that is exactly why I can't get it to happen. I editted my post, and I wrote, the file is **Empty** maybe empty cannot be converted to a JSON object! :) thus the exception. :) Thanks, I would try to add an empty object in the JSON file at the creation time! :) Thanks alot...

Comment: if the file is empty, then your `fs.Length` would be zero... you can have an `if` statement... but I would create an `if (!IsStreamValid(fs)) throw new Exception("This file sucks, read the manual!")` kind'a method before it does any conversion...

Comment: Yes, an empty file is not a valid JSON object. The structure of an empty JSON object would be: **{ }**

So your file should at least contain **{ }**

Answer (score 0):

The exception of `System.FormatException` gets thrown when there was error converting data and constructing an object.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.formatexception.aspx

In my file, the error was that the File was initially empty. Not even a single object was there, which would be a possible JSON object. So, the File content was not perfect fit for the JSON Standards. Thus the Exception got thrown.

I changed that, and used a simple, `if else` block to check for the contents. It was fixed this way.